# How ad retargeting works?

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, ads

Recently, I read that Facebook ads are moving towards retargeting and got interested deeper into subject. Essentially, retargeting is technique advertisers use that tracks purchase intent by putting cookies into your browser and when you visit another website within ad network you will see ad for item you "wanted to buy".

In order for this to work, both publisher and advertiser need  to work together. Publisher needs add couple of lines of JavaScript and publisher need to be able to read this info across sites. In most cases, JavaScript inserts iframe from adnetwork domain. The iframe script sets cookies for both host domain and remote adnetwork domain.

However, the Same Origin policy does not let `iframes` read/set content from parent domain.

Is there something I'm missing here? Can someone explain how this technique actually works?

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question

Comment: javascript can insert an iframe with URL and specify some parameters at the end of this URL like `...some_ad.php?product=some_id&country=country_id...`

Comment: @haynar that might explain how iframe sends info to ad server. but, not sure I understand how iframe reads cookies across ad network

Comment: Why did this question have to be locked? Would have been useful. Fwiw it would be off-topic on programmers.